# CDC operation type 3 shows a NULL value, even though it wasn't changed

Tags: sql-server, azure, change-data-capture

I have enabled CDC on a table in Azure SQL Server that is incorrectly tracking a column changing from NULL to 0, even though that column is never updated.

The column in question 'ColumnMob' is defined as follows;

```
[ColumnMob] [bit] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DFColumnMob] DEFAULT ((0))
```

The CDC table shows a large volume of instances that this column is being updated from a value of NULL, to 0, for operation 3 and 4, see example below;

| __$start_lsn | __$operation | __$seqval | ColumnMob |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0x00155AD70000DDB80050 | 3 | 0x00155AD600014A20001E | NULL |
| 0x00155AD70000DDB80050 | 4 | 0x00155AD600014A20001E | 0 |

How would this column track as changing from NULL to 0, when a procedure runs that updates other columns for example?

Comment: Possibly the column was added with a default after the rows were inserted, and those rows have never been rewritten since?

Comment: If sample scripts are shared, we can reproduce and check the issue.